# php - Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql

Table Structure:

```
user table:
id:int
user:varchar
hash:varchar
realm:int

Game Table:
ID:int:auto
Game:varchar
Password:varchar
Difficulty:tinytext
Realm:tinytext
Empty:int
timestamp:int

Player Table:
ID:Int
GameID:INT
Name:varchar
timestamp:int
```

When im trying to fetch_assoc() i'm getting error:

Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

```
function RequestToRemove($Hash, $timestamp)
    {
        include "conf.php";
        $conn = new mysqli($serverip, $username, $password, $dbname, $Port);
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 
        $hash = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $Hash);
        $UserQuerry = "SELECT * from User where hash = '$hash'";
        $UserResult = $conn->query($UserQuerry);
        if (!$UserResult) {
             echo "hash not found: ".$hash;
        }
        if ($UserResult->num_rows > 0) 
        {

            while($UserRow = $resulti->fetch_assoc()) 
            {
               $PlayerQuerry = "SELECT * from Players where ID = '".$UserRow['id']."'";
               $PlayerResult = $conn->query($PlayerQuerry);
               while($PlayerRow = $PlayerResult->fetch_assoc()) 
                {
                    $gameID = $PlayerRow['GameID'];
                    $gameQuerry = "SELECT * from games where ID = '$gameID'";
                    $gameResult = $conn->query($gameQuerry);
                    if ($gameResult->num_rows > 0) 
                    {
                        while($GameRow = $gameResult->fetch_assoc()) 
                        {
                            if((int)$GameRow['timestamp'] <= ($timestamp - 30) && (int)$GameRow['Empty'] == 1)
                            {
                                $gameDeleteQuerry = "DELETE FROM games where id = '".$gameID."'";
                                $conn->query($gameDeleteQuerry);
                                echo "Game Updated";
                            }
                        }
                        $playerDeleteQuerry = "DELETE FROM Players where id = '$gameID'";
                        $gamesUpdateQuerry = "UPDATE games SET timestamp='$timestamp' where ID = '$gameID'";
                        $gamesUpdateResult = $conn->query($gamesUpdateQuerry);
                        if (!$gamesUpdateResult) {
                            echo "Can't UPDATE game! ID: $gameID Error: ". $conn->error;
                            return;
                        }
                        $conn->query($playerDeleteQuerry);
                        $PlayerQuerry = "SELECT * from players where GameID = '$gameID'";
                        $PlayerResult = $conn->query($PlayerQuerry);
                        if (!$PlayerResult) {
                            echo "Can't get players! Error: " . $conn->Error;
                            return;
                        }
                        if ($PlayerResult->num_rows <= 0) {
                            $gameUpdateEmptyQuerry = "UPDATE games SET Empty='1' where GameID = '".$gameID."'";
                            $conn->query($gameUpdateEmptyQuerry);
                        }

                    } else {
                        echo "0 results";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $conn->close();
    }
```

but when im running

```
SELECT * from User where hash = 'ae3cb232b5e489050bfed7ed984eb04c'
```

in HeidiSQL
i will get one row in response but i can't still fetch_assoc() in php

Reason for edit: Show full function, requested

Comment: well that was just a typo i did here ^^ @Fred-ii-

Comment: after fixing the typo it`s working?

Comment: still not woking. the $Hash = "ae3cb232b5e489050bfed7ed984eb04c"; its just an example the hash its the session

Comment: what  is the column type for the column and how long is it in length? edit: Ok, it's "text". Use `varchar` instead and make sure it's higher than 32.

Comment: plus,  where are these defined? `$serverip, $username, $password, $dbname, $Port` and you may not need to use the port

Comment: are you doing something to `$resulti` in the `while` - loop?

Comment: @Fred-ii- in conf.php just not included in example other function works fine but not this one

Comment: is the column long enough for it? plus as I said, use `varchar` instead of `text`.

Comment: @cypherabe culd that be it? its a long code so i did not include it

Comment: yeah that `{..}` is obscure.

Comment: @user3050767 yes it could be, if you accidentally reassign `$resulti` or unset/free it, it will be invalid for the next iteration - the while condition is checked on every iteration of the loop with the at that moment existing values in the variables

Comment: Try this. Remove `$hash = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $Hash);` and do `where hash = '$Hash'";` if the error disappears, it's because of that line. `mysqli_escape_string` may be playing some mean tricks on you.

Comment: it's this line `while($row = $resultu->fetch_assoc())` and not what you posted originally. You're using `$resultu` against `$result = $conn->query($sql);` There is NO `$resultu` defined. Error reporting would have thrown you an undefined variable resultu notice.

Comment: Ohh..these nested while statements. Which fetch_assoc() ? The first one? Throw some debug stuff in `var_dump($result->num_rows);` or `$row_cnt = $result->num_rows; printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);` to see where things go wrong. And check your variable names on the result sets: $resulti, $resultu, $resulty.. prone to errors.

Comment: @JensA.Koch nwm im getting one row

Comment: your code is so hard to follow, it's making my head spin. You have queries calling different variables right and left. I have an answer ready based on `$resultu`, but I'm afraid to undelete it.

Comment: you're getting one row, because of what??

Comment: I will name my vars diffrent so it will hel a bit :)

Comment: then this `where ID = '".$rowi['id']` - `id` and `ID` are two different animals altogether for the `$rowi['id']`. so, where are we here? solved? not? if solved, based on what?

Comment: @Fred-ii- that fixed it now is that it takes ages for server to respond cuz of while loops so im getting Time out ;/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91751/discussion-between-user3050767-and-fred-ii).

Answer (score 0):

you are reassigning a different value to `$resulti` within the loop:

```
$sqll = "DELETE FROM Players where id = '$gameID'";
$sqlu = "UPDATE games SET timestamp='$timestamp' where ID = '$gameID'";
$resulti = $conn->query($sqlu);
```

the mysqli::query() function is tricky, it can return different type of return values - an update statement returns either true or false, whereas a select statement returns a mysqli_result or false.

(and yes, it may help to name the variables a bit more descriptive ;) )

Comment: i found that typo before you posted ^^